# How to have hyperref correctly refer to phantom sections without clearing a double page

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref

When using starred sections in a double page layout, in order to get the table of contents refer to the correct place, it is usually advised to use the method

```
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\chapter*{Introduction}
```

Yet this creates a blank page if the page is not odd numbered. In my case, I want to have two starred sections side by side and correctly referenced by the TOC and hyperref. Is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Edit : Sorry for the lack of precisions. I am working with the book class, and here is an example of this problem:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Left Side}
\chapter*{Left side}
\end{document}
```

The link to Left Side refers to the wrong page, clearing two pages instead does the trick but that's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I just use `\chapter*` followed by the `\phantomsection` and the `\addcontentsline`. In `memoir` at least the `\chapter*` clears the page if necessary.

Comment: Could you please post a complete minimum (working) example with several pages in it illustrating the problem. It would help the solvers to get fast into your problem.

Comment: The important point is that `\phantomsection` goes to the very same page, where the chapter title is set. If `\chapter` internally uses `\cleardoublepage`, then you need `\cleardoublepage`. Otherwise `\clearpage` or `\newpage` (if there are not pending floating objects) suffices.

Comment: Oh right thank you for this comment Heiko. Now I realize how stupid this question was. The chapter environment clears two pages anyway, so the solution lies there, not within hyperref or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\clearpage` rather than `\cleardoublepage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\chapter*{Left side}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Left Side}
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with the book class, the hyperlink sends to the wrong page.

Comment: @Arnaud: Please see the update...

Comment: this is not very satsifying either, as the hyperlink goes directly after the chapter title (i.e. the chapter title is cut out). As I was saying in a comment to the main question though, I realize that the question is off the mark now, since the cleardoublepage is present in the chapter environment anyway, so there is no reason not to use /cleardoublepage.

Comment: @Arnaud: When I compile the above MWE, the `\phantomsection` hyperlinks point to the top of the text block on the chapter page (exactly where it is supposed to be), making the title clearly visible.

Comment: This is weird, when I compile it the hyperlink goes just under the Left side (I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) )